# Using the FormatMessage function with arguments in Delphi

Tags: winapi, delphi-11-alexandria

I'm having trouble entering the arguments: how do you pass an `array of const` correctly to the `Arguments` parameter of the function?

I tried the:

```pascal
function FormatMessageFromString(const AFormat: string; Args: array of const): string;
var
  Buffer: PChar;
  ArgList: Pointer;
begin
  ArgList := nil;
  if Length(Args) > 0 then
  begin
    ArgList := @Args[0];
  end;

  if FormatMessage(
    FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_STRING or FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER or FORMAT_MESSAGE_ARGUMENT_ARRAY,
    PChar(AFormat),
    0,
    0,
    @Buffer,
    0,
    ArgList) <> 0 then
  try
    Result := Buffer;
  finally
    LocalFree(HLOCAL(Buffer));
  end
  else
    RaiseLastOSError;
end;
```

but the only thing I get is an access violation...

I also tried this (from [here](https://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2010/03/28/using-windows-resource-strings/)):

```pascal
function FormatMsg(const Source: String; const Args: array of const): String;
var
  i: Integer;
  ArgArray: array of Pointer;
  Buffer: PChar;
begin
  for i := Low(Args) to High(Args) do
  begin
    SetLength(ArgArray, i+1);
    case Args[i].VType  of
      vtExtended:; // not supported, should raise Exception
    else
      ArgArray[i] := Args[i].VPointer;
    end;
  end;

  if FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_STRING or
    FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER or FORMAT_MESSAGE_ARGUMENT_ARRAY,
    PChar(Source), 0, 0, @Buffer, 0, @ArgArray[0]) > 0 then
  begin
    Result := Buffer;
    // replace \n (linefeed) with #13#10
    Result := StringReplace(Result, '\n', #13#10, [rfReplaceAll]);
    LocalFree(DWORD(Buffer));
  end
  else begin
    SetLength(Result, 0);
  end;
end;
```

I just get unrecognized characters.

I couldn't figure out from the documentation what kind of array I should provide from Delphi (I want to use "pure" winapi calls only).

I would love to get help!!

Thanks!

Comment: `array of const` is not the correct memory layout for `FORMAT_MESSAGE_ARGUMENT_ARRAY`. `FORMAT_MESSAGE_ARGUMENT_ARRAY` wants a pointer to an array of `DWORD_PTR`, but `array of const` is a pointer to an array of `TVarRec`. You will have to convert the array of `TVarRec` to an array of `DWORD_PTR`.

Comment: Your 2nd approach is what you need to do, however 1) don't use `SetLength()` on each loop iteration, use `SetLength(ArgArray, Length(Args));` before entering the loop, and 2) using `Args[i].VPointer` is wrong for non-pointer types. You will have to interpret and convert each [`TVarRec`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TVarRec) value individually based on its actual `VType` and what the `Source` string [is asking for](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/format-specification-syntax-printf-and-wprintf-functions?view=msvc-170#type) from each `TVarRec` value.